# Unity3D Android Plugin to communicate (send data) to Arduino Uno

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, arduino

I am developing an android app which communicates to Arduino through Unity. Basically creating a jar file and placing it in plugins folder and building for Android.

I am using the google docs for USB host as reference, and some code from the Internet modified for Unity.

All the xml files, intent are correct and the app runs.

When I call Test(), The button in Unity works the first time and the app becomes unresponsive. Data is not sent to the Arduino but the test phone(Samsung Galaxy S4).

When I connect the Arduino the phone recognizes it and when I start the app the screen goes black. Disconnecting the Arduino and reconnecting allows me to use the Button once.

I call the function with mContext.

I have tried a few things but the data is not received by the Arduino and the app hangs.

Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity{

private static final char CMD_LED_OFF = '1';
private static final char CMD_LED_ON = '2';

private UsbManager usbManager;
private UsbDevice deviceFound;
private UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection;
private UsbInterface usbInterfaceFound = null;
private UsbEndpoint endpointOut = null;
private UsbEndpoint endpointIn = null;

public static Context mContext;
private static MainActivity mActivity;

public static MainActivity mActivity(){
    if(mActivity == null)
    {
        mActivity = new MainActivity();
    }
    return mActivity;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Create Working", "onCreate: ");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    usbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
}


public void Test()
{
    Log.d("Led","Light On");
    sendCommand(CMD_LED_ON);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d("Resume", "Something is suppose to happen here");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
        setDevice(device);
    } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
        if (deviceFound != null && deviceFound.equals(device)) {
            setDevice(null);
        }
    }
}

private void setDevice(UsbDevice device) {
    usbInterfaceFound = null;
    endpointOut = null;
    endpointIn = null;
    Log.d("Set Device","Working");

    for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
        UsbInterface usbif = device.getInterface(i);

        UsbEndpoint tOut = null;
        UsbEndpoint tIn = null;

        int tEndpointCnt = usbif.getEndpointCount();
        if (tEndpointCnt >= 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tEndpointCnt; j++) {
                if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                    if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
                        tOut = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
                    } else if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                        tIn = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (tOut != null && tIn != null) {
                // This interface have both USB_DIR_OUT
                // and USB_DIR_IN of USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK
                usbInterfaceFound = usbif;
                endpointOut = tOut;
                endpointIn = tIn;
            }
        }

    }

    if (usbInterfaceFound == null) {
        return;
    }

    deviceFound = device;

    if (device != null) {
        UsbDeviceConnection connection =
                usbManager.openDevice(device);
        if (connection != null &&
                connection.claimInterface(usbInterfaceFound, true)) {
            usbDeviceConnection = connection;
            UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            {
                                Log.d("Run","Does Something");
                                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
                                UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
                                request.initialize(usbDeviceConnection, endpointIn);
                                while (true) {
                                    Log.d("Run","Does something else in run");
                                    request.queue(buffer, 1);
                                    if (usbDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request) {
                                        byte rxCmd = buffer.get(0);
                                        if(rxCmd!=0){
                                            //how to update rxCmd without GUI
                                            //bar.setProgress((int)rxCmd);
                                        }
                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(100);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            //Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            //thread.start();

        } else {
            usbDeviceConnection = null;
        }
    }
}


public void sendCommand(int control) {
    synchronized (this) {
        Log.d("Send","Enters");
        if (usbDeviceConnection != null) {
            Log.d("Send","Entered");
            byte[] message = new byte[1];
            message[0] = (byte)control;
            usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut,
                    message, message.length, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Call from Unity

```
using (AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.compname.projectname.MainActivity"))
    {
        using (AndroidJavaObject activity = javaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mContext"))
        {
            activity.Call("Test");    
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I have tried a few things"* it would probably help us know what you tried, so no one tries to propose a solution that isn't going to work.

Comment: Tried running on different thread, tried without thread, tried to place thread differently,  tried different calls from Unity to Android, Android to Unity. I think I am missing something in Runnable, a loop which does not end and causes the app to hang.